# Hibernate + c3p0 Pool + ehcache fail start

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache, c3p0

I have a JavaFX application which works fine until I add a 2º cache (ehcache with regions). After that, I start application but I get this error when try to create session factory:

```
08/10/2014 20:01:40 DEBUG Configuration:1841 - Preparing to build session factory with filters : {}
08/10/2014 20:01:40 INFO  ConnectionProviderInitiator:190 - HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
Exception in Application start method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

These are my files (I ommited private data):

**hibernate.cfg:**

```
<property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</property>
<property name="connection.release_mode">auto</property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="show_sql">false</property>
<property name="format_sql">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">3000</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
<!-- If I remove this line, I get an error which said something like region name is not defined --->
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
```

**POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>terracotta-releases</id>
        <url>http://www.terracotta.org/download/reflector/releases</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>       
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.33</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.GA</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

**ehcache.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="true" monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="true">


    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

    <defaultCache
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120"
        timeToLiveSeconds="120"
        diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
        maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
        statistics="false">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
    </defaultCache>

    <cache name="region1"
           maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
           maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000"
           eternal="false"
           diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
           timeToIdleSeconds="300"
           timeToLiveSeconds="600"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
           transactionalMode="off">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
    </cache>

</ehcache>
```

**hibernateUtil**

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public enum Util {
      INSTANCE;
     private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Util() {
        Configuration configuration;
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder;

        configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
    }

    public static Util getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

When I try to debug, stop at         `sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());` because session return is null. But if I remove pool, session works.

Also, on all *.hbm.xml files, I set cache by putting `<cache usage="nonstrict-read-write" region="region1"/>`. If I remove region, starts but I get an error because I don't defined a region and hibernate takes default name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I fix the problem by myselft. Here are the answer:

hibernate.cfg

```
    <!-- Pool -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">3000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
    <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <!-- Cache -->
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
    <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache.xml</property>
```

NOTE: if you use a singleton in your sessionFactory class, then use `SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory` class, if not, then use `org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory`.

Some latest dependencies version not work well with above configuracion, so I need to use previous in some cases.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
                <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.33</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.7</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.GA</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.2.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

And ehcache.xml with cache configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="true" monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="true">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir/ehcache" />

    <defaultCache maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000" eternal="false"
                  timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120" diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
                  maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
                  memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" statistics="true">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </defaultCache>

    <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache"
           maxEntriesLocalHeap="5" eternal="false" timeToLiveSeconds="120">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>

    <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache"
           maxEntriesLocalHeap="5000" eternal="true">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>
</ehcache>
```

NOTE: This file works OK, but logs report warnings because I don't specified cache for current beans, so cache take default configuration. Also, I get some warning about mchange dependency file which mcach couldn't find but really it's not a error so don't worry about that kind of warns.