# Hibernate + HikariCP + EHCache session creation fails

Tags: hibernate, ehcache, hikaricp

Previously, I configured well Hibernate + c3p0 + ehcache as show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26263861/hibernate-c3p0-pool-ehcache-fail-start) Now, I try to use a more powerful pool like HikariCP. First, I try to configure Hibernate + HikariCP as show [in this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789871/hibernate-fails-create-sessionfactory-using-hikaricp-pool).

Until now, I can use well Hibernate with HikariCP but, when I add EHCache (as show in first link) app fails start. I don't get an error, only app stops try create sessionfactory.

**LOG** (I remove some similar lines because stackoverflow don't let me put full log because is very long).

```
    NetBeans: JPDA Listening Start...
    JPDA Address: ******:50991
    Port:50991
    cd D:\****\Código; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_40" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0.1\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Drunfx.args=\"-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=50991 -jar ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar\" -Djpda.listen=true -DskipTests=true -Djpda.address=50991 -Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\\Users\\Marcos\\AppData\\Roaming\\NetBeans\\8.0.1\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec\""
    Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
    Scanning for projects...

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Building **** 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    The artifact xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2 has been relocated to xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2

    --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ **** ---
    Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4jLoggerProvider
    Adding type registration boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@601bc59e
    .....
    HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
    HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.7.Final}
    HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
    Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [uuid2] -> [org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator]
    Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [guid] -> [org.hibernate.id.GUIDGenerator]
    Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [uuid] -> [org.hibernate.id.UUIDHexGenerator]
    Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [uuid.hex] -> [org.hibernate.id.UUIDHexGenerator]
    Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [hilo] -> [org.hibernate.id.TableHiLoGenerator]
    Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [assigned] -> [org.hibernate.id.Assigned]
    Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [identity] -> [org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator]
    Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [select] -> [org.hibernate.id.SelectGenerator]
    Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [sequence] -> [org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator]
    Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [seqhilo] -> [org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator]
    Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [increment] -> [org.hibernate.id.IncrementGenerator]
    Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [foreign] -> [org.hibernate.id.ForeignGenerator]
    Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [sequence-identity] -> [org.hibernate.id.SequenceIdentityGenerator]
    Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [enhanced-sequence] -> [org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator]
    Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [enhanced-table] -> [org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator]
    HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    Trying to resolve system-id [http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd]
    Recognized hibernate namespace; attempting to resolve on classpath under org/hibernate/
    Located [http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd] in classpath
    hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
    hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/****?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
    hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user=****
    hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password=****1
    javax.persistence.validation.mode=none
    connection.release_mode=after_transaction
    current_session_context_class=thread
    show_sql=true
    format_sql=true
    hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
    hibernate.connection.provider_class=com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider
    hibernate.hikari.dataSource.cachePrepStmts=true
    hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize=250
    hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
    hibernate.hikari.dataSource.useServerPrepStmts=true
    hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
    hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
    hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
    hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
    net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName=/ehcache.xml
    Session-factory config [null] named resource [com/****/mapeos/****.hbm.xml] for mapping
    HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/****/mapeos/****.hbm.xml
    Trying to resolve system-id [http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd]
    Recognized hibernate namespace; attempting to resolve on classpath under org/hibernate/
    Located [http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd] in classpath
    Session-factory config [null] named resource [com/****/mapeos/****.hbm.xml] for mapping
    HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/****/mapeos/****.hbm.xml
    Trying to resolve system-id [http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd]
    Recognized hibernate namespace; attempting to resolve on classpath under org/hibernate/
    Located [http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd] in classpath
    Session-factory config [null] named resource [com/****/mapeos/****.hbm.xml] for mapping
    HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/****/mapeos/****.hbm.xml
    Trying to resolve system-id [http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd]
    Recognized hibernate namespace; attempting to resolve on classpath under org/hibernate/
    Located [http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd] in classpath
    Session-factory config [null] named resource [com/****/mapeos/********.hbm.xml] for mapping
    HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/****/mapeos/********.hbm.xml
    Trying to resolve system-id [http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd]
    Recognized hibernate namespace; attempting to resolve on classpath under org/hibernate/
    Located [http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd] in classpath
    Session-factory config [null] named resource [com/****/mapeos/****.hbm.xml] for mapping
    HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/****/mapeos/****.hbm.xml
    Trying to resolve system-id [http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd]
    Recognized hibernate namespace; attempting to resolve on classpath under org/hibernate/
    Located [http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd] in classpath
    Session-factory config [null] named resource [com/****/mapeos/****.hbm.xml] for mapping
    HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/****/mapeos/****.hbm.xml
    Trying to resolve system-id [http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd]
    Recognized hibernate namespace; attempting to resolve on classpath under org/hibernate/
    Located [http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd] in classpath
    Session-factory config [null] named resource [com/****/mapeos/********.hbm.xml] for mapping
    HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/****/mapeos/********.hbm.xml
    Trying to resolve system-id [http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd]
    Recognized hibernate namespace; attempting to resolve on classpath under org/hibernate/
    Located [http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd] in classpath
    Session-factory config [null] named resource [com/****/mapeos/****.hbm.xml] for mapping
    HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/****/mapeos/****.hbm.xml
    Trying to resolve system-id [http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd]
    Recognized hibernate namespace; attempting to resolve on classpath under org/hibernate/
    Located [http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd] in classpath
    Session-factory config [null] named resource [com/****/mapeos/****Categoria.hbm.xml] for mapping
    HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/****/mapeos/****Categoria.hbm.xml
    Trying to resolve system-id [http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd]
    Recognized hibernate namespace; attempting to resolve on classpath under org/hibernate/
    Located [http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd] in classpath
    HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
    Properties: {java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, show_sql=true, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers, os.name=Windows 8.1, sun.boot.class.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\classes, hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false, hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread, sun.desktop=windows, java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.runtime.version=1.8.0_40-ea-b11, hibernate.hikari.dataSource.cachePrepStmts=true, hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider, user.name=Marcos, javax.persistence.validation.mode=none, hibernate.connection.release_mode=after_transaction, current_session_context_class=thread, javafx.runtime.version=8.0.40-ea-b11, user.language=es, hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048, sun.boot.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\bin, hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize=250, java.version=1.8.0_40-ea, user.timezone=Europe/Paris, sun.arch.data.model=64, java.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\endorsed, sun.cpu.isalist=amd64, sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252, file.encoding.pkg=sun.io, file.separator=\, java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification, hibernate.format_sql=true, java.class.version=52.0, user.country=ES, java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre, java.vm.info=mixed mode, os.version=6.3, path.separator=;, java.vm.version=25.40-b15, hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory, user.variant=, java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob, sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle, awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit, hibernate.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none, user.script=, user.home=C:\Users\Marcos, java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user=****, java.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5;C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\cygwin64;D:\Servidor\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin;D:\Servidor\bin\php\php5.3.13;D:\Servidor\bin\php\php5.3.13\pear;D:\Servidor\bin\php\php5.3.13\imagick;D:\Servidor\tools\imagemagick\imagemagick6.8.9-7;D:\Servidor\tools\svn\svn1.7.14\bin;D:\Servidor\tools\git\git1.8.4\bin;;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;., java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/, java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect, java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, sun.java.command=D:\****\Código\target/****-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, java.class.path=D:\****\Código\target/****-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, hibernate.net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName=/ehcache.xml, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password=****1, java.vm.specification.version=1.8, hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true, sun.cpu.endian=little, hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/****?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull, sun.os.patch.level=, hibernate.connection.provider_class=com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider, java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Temp\, java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/, connection.release_mode=after_transaction, os.arch=amd64, java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment, java.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\ext;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext, user.dir=D:\****\Código, line.separator=
    , java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource, hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true, javafx.version=8.0.40-ea, file.encoding=Cp1252, format_sql=true, java.specification.version=1.8, net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName=/ehcache.xml, hibernate.hikari.dataSource.useServerPrepStmts=true, hibernate.show_sql=true}
    Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator].
    Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.secure.spi.JaccIntegrator].
    Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.cache.internal.CollectionCacheInvalidator].
    Registering named strategy selector [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] : [MySQL5] -> [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect] (replacing [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect])
    Registering named strategy selector [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] : [MySQL5InnoDB] -> [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect] (replacing [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect])
    Overriding existing service binding [org.hibernate.secure.spi.JaccService]
    Preparing to build session factory with filters : {}
    HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider
    Configuring HikariCP
    HikariCP pool HikariPool-0 configuration:
    autoCommit......................true
    catalog.........................
    connectionCustomizer............com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig$1@13fcc3f0
    connectionCustomizerClassName...
    connectionInitSql...............
    connectionTestQuery.............
    connectionTimeout...............30000
    dataSource......................
    dataSourceClassName.............com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
    dataSourceJNDI..................
    dataSourceProperties............{user=****, password=<masked>, url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/****?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull, prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048, useServerPrepStmts=true, cachePrepStmts=true, prepStmtCacheSize=250}
    driverClassName.................
    idleTimeout.....................600000
    initializationFailFast..........false
    isolateInternalQueries..........false
    jdbc4ConnectionTest.............true
    jdbcUrl.........................
    leakDetectionThreshold..........0
    maxLifetime.....................1800000
    maximumPoolSize.................10
    metricsTrackerClassName.........com.zaxxer.hikari.metrics.CodaHaleMetricsTracker
    minimumIdle.....................10
    password........................<masked>
    poolName........................HikariPool-0
    readOnly........................false
    recordMetrics...................false
    registerMbeans..................false
    threadFactory...................
    transactionIsolation............
    username........................
    HikariCP pool HikariPool-0 is starting.
    HikariCP Configured
    HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
    Processing hbm.xml files
    Mapping class: com.****.modelos.**** -> ****
    Mapped property: id -> Id
    .........
    Process annotated classes
    Processing fk mappings (*ToOne and JoinedSubclass)
    Processing extends queue
    Processing extends queue
    Processing collection mappings
    Second pass for collection: com.****.modelos.****.****s
    Mapping collection: com.****.modelos.****.****s -> ****
    ..........
    Processing native query and ResultSetMapping mappings
    Processing association property references
    Creating tables' unique integer identifiers
    Processing foreign key constraints
    Resolving reference to class: com.****.modelos.****
    ............
    No JtaPlatform was specified, checking resolver
    No JtaPlatformResolver was specified, using default [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.StandardJtaPlatformResolver]
    Could not resolve JtaPlatform, using default [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
    Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
    Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
    Scrollable result sets: disabled
    Wrap result sets: disabled
    JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): disabled
    multi-tenancy strategy : NONE
    Connection release mode: after_transaction
    Using BatchFetchStyle : LEGACY
    Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2
    Default batch fetch size: 1
    Generate SQL with comments: disabled
    Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
    Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
    Default null ordering: none
    Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
    HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
    Query language substitutions: {}
    JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
    Second-level cache: enabled
    Query cache: enabled
    Query cache factory: org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCacheFactory
    Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
    Optimize cache for minimal puts: enabled
    Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
    Second-level cache direct-reference entries: disabled
    Automatic eviction of collection cache: disabled
    Statistics: disabled
    Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
    Default entity-mode: pojo
    Named query checking : enabled
    Check Nullability in Core (should be disabled when Bean Validation is on): enabled
    Allow initialization of lazy state outside session : : disabled
    JTA Track by Thread: enabled
    Building session factory
    Exception in Application start method
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:303)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$150(LauncherImpl.java:157)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$49/194494468.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.****.dao.****DAO.obtenLista****esPorEstado(****DAO.java:92)
        at com.****.controladores.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:52)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$156(LauncherImpl.java:821)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$52/718709938.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$169(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/863831416.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$167(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/530599638.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$168(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1508395126.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$144(WinApplication.java:101)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/2136344592.run(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
    Exception running application com.****.controladores.MainApp
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    BUILD FAILURE
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Total time: 8.154s
    Finished at: Sun Nov 09 16:50:23 CET 2014
    Final Memory: 7M/153M
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Part of hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <!-- Datos de conexión a la BD -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/******?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">****</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">****</property>
    <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</property>
    <!-- Configuración de sesión -->
    <property name="connection.release_mode">after_transaction</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <!-- Configuración de la salida SQL y estadísticas -->>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
    <!-- Pool de conexiones  (works well)-->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.cachePrepStmts">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize">250</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit">2048</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.useServerPrepStmts">true</property>

    <!-- Cache 2º nivel  (this not work, but If disable, works)-->
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
    <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache.xml</property>
```

I don't know what it's wrong.

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
public enum HibernateUtil {

    INSTANCE;
    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private HibernateUtil() {
        Configuration configuration;
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder;

        configuration = new Configuration().configure();

        builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
    }

    public static HibernateUtil getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

**POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   ......
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>terracotta-releases</id>
            <url>http://www.terracotta.org/download/reflector/releases</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.33</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.GA</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Pool de conexiones -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

UPDATE: I add files configuration for more info.

Comment: What version of HikariCP, Hibernate, Ecache, and Java?

Comment: HikariCP 2.1.0; Hibernate 4.3.7; EhCache 2.9.0; Java 1.8.0_40-ea-b11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove these lines:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/******?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">****</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">****</property>
```

with the following ones:

```
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource</property>
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/******?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user">****</property>
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password">****</property>
```

The first JDBC configuration properties are only meant if you want to use Hibernate internal connection pooling solution.

You need to add the hibernate.cfg.xml to your Configuration:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().addResource("hibernate.cfg.xml").configure();
```

Comment: I try it your solution but still not works. I get same error, and also, I try to configure debug level to get max info, but always return same error as I show above.

Comment: I put log in question, also I try your update but I get same error.

Comment: I think, I finally get real error: `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.ehcache.util.ClassLoaderUtil.getStandardClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;` I need to add `throws HibernateException` to `HibernateUtil` so I can see error.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thanks to @vlad-mihalcea for his help.

Afte follow his solution, I identify problem was because ehCache try to access some clas from same jar that I exclude in my pom:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
                <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Remove exclusion and all works fine:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```